# Loop through JSON Array into android sql lite database by tag?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have a function that gets back JSON. Here is the format for my question of JSON.

```
    [{"ChapterNum":"1","CourseID":"37","ChapterID":"30"},
    {"ChapterNum":"2","CourseID":"37","ChapterID":"31"},    
    {"ChapterNum":"3","CourseID":"37","ChapterID":"32"}]
```

I basically want to take the "ChapterNum" with its value and store it into my android sqlite database.

I am just confused how to loop through it and put it into my DB...

for a previous db entry to do this.

```
public long addStudentInfoToDb(String stuID,String stuFName, String stuLName) {
    ContentValues student_info = new ContentValues();

    student_info.put(STU_ID, stuID);
    student_info.put(STU_FNAME, stuFName);
    student_info.put(STU_LNAME, stuLName);
    return mDb.insert("Student", null, student_info);

}
```

so I was thinking like

```
public long addChaptersToDb() {
    ContentValues chapter_info = new ContentValues();



    ///loop through jArray
            ///read array into contentvalues





    return mDb.insert("Chapter", null, chapter_info);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public long addChaptersToDb() {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       String chapterNum =  jsonData.getString("ChapterNum");
       String courseID = jsonData.getString("CourseID");
       String chapterID = jsonData.getString("ChapterID");

       ContentValues chapter_info = new ContentValues();
       chapter_info.put(ChapterNum, chapterNum);
       chapter_info.put(CourseID, courseID);
       chapter_info.put(ChapterID, chapterID);

       mDb.insert("Chapter", null, chapter_info);
    }
}
```